# PHP pChart change color of bars of bar chart

Tags: php, codeigniter, charts, pchart

I am developing php statistic part of my app with pChart, but I met a difficulty trying to set the colors of my bars with the pChart librairy. I want to change color of each bar. Is it possible to change the color ? Like for slices ?

My chart just has 1 serie, I have 4 bars.

With Pie chart I can use this

```
$PieChart = $this->pchart->pPie($myPicture,$MyData);
$PieChart->setSliceColor(0,array("R"=>255,"G"=>128,"B"=>0));
$PieChart->setSliceColor(1,array("R"=>255,"G"=>255,"B"=>255));
$PieChart->setSliceColor(2,array("R"=>25,"G"=>128,"B"=>0));
$PieChart->setSliceColor(4,array("R"=>55,"G"=>255,"B"=>25));
```

How will I manage it with bars ? I have no indication on documentation.

Comment: Have you tried to change values for RGB range ( 0 - 255 )?

Comment: @Tpojka let me know how ?

Comment: Have you read the [manual](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/documentation.php?topic=faq.colors)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that, but you have to use custom palette for that.

```
$Palette = array("0"=>array("R"=>188,"G"=>224,"B"=>46,"Alpha"=>100),
                 "1"=>array("R"=>224,"G"=>100,"B"=>46,"Alpha"=>100),
                 "2"=>array("R"=>224,"G"=>214,"B"=>46,"Alpha"=>100),
                 "3"=>array("R"=>46,"G"=>151,"B"=>224,"Alpha"=>100),
                 "4"=>array("R"=>176,"G"=>46,"B"=>224,"Alpha"=>100),
                 "5"=>array("R"=>224,"G"=>46,"B"=>117,"Alpha"=>100),
                 "6"=>array("R"=>92,"G"=>224,"B"=>46,"Alpha"=>100),
                 "7"=>array("R"=>224,"G"=>176,"B"=>46,"Alpha"=>100));

$myPicture->drawBarChart(array("OverrideColors"=>$Palette));
```

If you want more info you can find it here. http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.chart.drawbarchart.html